# Can't find the "esUtil.h" in an OpenGL ES example

Tags: c++, opengl-es

After learning some basics in OpenGL, I'm diving into the OpenGL ES API. I am attempting to use this example to draw a triangle in OpenGL ES: https://www.khronos.org/assets/uploads/books/openglr_es_20_programming_guide_sample.pdf.

In the code, the author includes the file "esUtil.h", but I can't find it from any official source. I tried to copied "esUtil.h" file of some project on google with the EGL and GLES 3 libraries but the program still can't run at all. Help me, what am i missing ?

These are the errors i got from building the solution:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glAttachShader@8 referenced in function "int __cdecl Init(struct ESContext *)" (?Init@@YAHPAUESContext@@@Z)   OpenGLES_Example    D:\WorkSpace\Visual Studio\myOpenGLSamples\OpenGLES_Example\Source.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glCompileShader@4 referenced in function "unsigned int __cdecl LoadShader(unsigned int,char const *)" (?LoadShader@@YAIIPBD@Z)    OpenGLES_Example    D:\WorkSpace\Visual Studio\myOpenGLSamples\OpenGLES_Example\Source.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glCreateProgram@0 referenced in function "int __cdecl Init(struct ESContext *)" (?Init@@YAHPAUESContext@@@Z)  OpenGLES_Example    D:\WorkSpace\Visual Studio\myOpenGLSamples\OpenGLES_Example\Source.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glCreateShader@4 referenced in function "unsigned int __cdecl LoadShader(unsigned int,char const *)" (?LoadShader@@YAIIPBD@Z) OpenGLES_Example    D:\WorkSpace\Visual Studio\myOpenGLSamples\OpenGLES_Example\Source.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glDeleteProgram@4 referenced in function "int __cdecl Init(struct ESContext *)" (?Init@@YAHPAUESContext@@@Z)  OpenGLES_Example    D:\WorkSpace\Visual Studio\myOpenGLSamples\OpenGLES_Example\Source.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glDeleteShader@4 referenced in function "unsigned int __cdecl LoadShader(unsigned int,char const *)" (?LoadShader@@YAIIPBD@Z) OpenGLES_Example    D:\WorkSpace\Visual Studio\myOpenGLSamples\OpenGLES_Example\Source.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glEnableVertexAttribArray@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl Draw(struct ESContext *)" (?Draw@@YAXPAUESContext@@@Z)   OpenGLES_Example    D:\WorkSpace\Visual Studio\myOpenGLSamples\OpenGLES_Example\Source.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glGetProgramiv@12 referenced in function "int __cdecl Init(struct ESContext *)" (?Init@@YAHPAUESContext@@@Z)  OpenGLES_Example    D:\WorkSpace\Visual Studio\myOpenGLSamples\OpenGLES_Example\Source.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glGetProgramInfoLog@16 referenced in function "int __cdecl Init(struct ESContext *)" (?Init@@YAHPAUESContext@@@Z) OpenGLES_Example    D:\WorkSpace\Visual Studio\myOpenGLSamples\OpenGLES_Example\Source.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glGetShaderiv@12 referenced in function "unsigned int __cdecl LoadShader(unsigned int,char const *)" (?LoadShader@@YAIIPBD@Z) OpenGLES_Example    D:\WorkSpace\Visual Studio\myOpenGLSamples\OpenGLES_Example\Source.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glGetShaderInfoLog@16 referenced in function "unsigned int __cdecl LoadShader(unsigned int,char const *)" (?LoadShader@@YAIIPBD@Z)    OpenGLES_Example    D:\WorkSpace\Visual Studio\myOpenGLSamples\OpenGLES_Example\Source.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glLinkProgram@4 referenced in function "int __cdecl Init(struct ESContext *)" (?Init@@YAHPAUESContext@@@Z)    OpenGLES_Example    D:\WorkSpace\Visual Studio\myOpenGLSamples\OpenGLES_Example\Source.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glShaderSource@16 referenced in function "unsigned int __cdecl LoadShader(unsigned int,char const *)" (?LoadShader@@YAIIPBD@Z)    OpenGLES_Example    D:\WorkSpace\Visual Studio\myOpenGLSamples\OpenGLES_Example\Source.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glUseProgram@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl Draw(struct ESContext *)" (?Draw@@YAXPAUESContext@@@Z)    OpenGLES_Example    D:\WorkSpace\Visual Studio\myOpenGLSamples\OpenGLES_Example\Source.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glVertexAttribPointer@24 referenced in function "void __cdecl Draw(struct ESContext *)" (?Draw@@YAXPAUESContext@@@Z)  OpenGLES_Example    D:\WorkSpace\Visual Studio\myOpenGLSamples\OpenGLES_Example\Source.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _esCreateWindow referenced in function "int __cdecl esMain(struct ESContext *)" (?esMain@@YAHPAUESContext@@@Z)   OpenGLES_Example    D:\WorkSpace\Visual Studio\myOpenGLSamples\OpenGLES_Example\Source.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _esRegisterDrawFunc referenced in function "int __cdecl esMain(struct ESContext *)" (?esMain@@YAHPAUESContext@@@Z)   OpenGLES_Example    D:\WorkSpace\Visual Studio\myOpenGLSamples\OpenGLES_Example\Source.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _esRegisterShutdownFunc referenced in function "int __cdecl esMain(struct ESContext *)" (?esMain@@YAHPAUESContext@@@Z)   OpenGLES_Example    D:\WorkSpace\Visual Studio\myOpenGLSamples\OpenGLES_Example\Source.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _esLogMessage referenced in function "int __cdecl Init(struct ESContext *)" (?Init@@YAHPAUESContext@@@Z) OpenGLES_Example    D:\WorkSpace\Visual Studio\myOpenGLSamples\OpenGLES_Example\Source.obj  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)   OpenGLES_Example    D:\WorkSpace\Visual Studio\myOpenGLSamples\OpenGLES_Example\MSVCRTD.lib(exe_main.obj)   1   
Error   LNK1120 20 unresolved externals OpenGLES_Example    D:\WorkSpace\Visual Studio\myOpenGLSamples\Debug\OpenGLES_Example.exe   1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These errors are not problems with including files, they are with linking. The symbols indicate you're missing the OpenGL ES libraries (`glAttachShader`, et al), and also some of the functions from the example code (appear to be from esUtil.c).

If you follow the download links in your tutorial, they lead to [here](https://github.com/danginsburg/opengles3-book). You might considering just cloning the `git` repository, and working from it. At minimum, the [esUtil.h](https://github.com/danginsburg/opengles3-book/blob/ff1b7de224de3389cd6a3f8b7bd7839cee0f551f/Common/Include/esUtil.h) file is under there, you will also need to compile [esUtil.c](https://github.com/danginsburg/opengles3-book/blob/ff1b7de224de3389cd6a3f8b7bd7839cee0f551f/Common/Source/esUtil.c) into your project, because some of those symbols are missing.